# Module has not been deployed in netbeans Error

Tags: java, netbeans

I am getting an error while running my netbeans web application..
Its saying

> C:\Users\Dhruv\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FinalProject\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1025:
>   The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details.

I got this error suddenly after adding a servlet to my project..
These are the lines in the xml file..

```
    <target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb"> 
    <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false"
forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/> </target>
```

Comment: I got this error suddenly after adding a servlet to my project.. These are the lines in the xml file.. 

               <target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
        <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
    </target>

Comment: Please edit your *question* if you have additional information.

Comment: you should edit the question rather putting comment below it

Comment: The ques is the same .. i jst thought the last part ws erased.. any useful tips which might help me??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.I just uninstalled the netbeans and installed it again.
When i installed it again i customized the configuration and made sure that i selected runtime as apache tomcat. 
May be this could anyone.